# How to zoom/pan in JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Is it possible to digitally zoom / pan in JWPlayer, either built-in function or via the API?

I tried searching their APIs docs and KB but couldn't find anything.

If the player doesn't expose this functionality, are there any browser tricks I could apply to achieve the same goal? or any other players in the market that do support it?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such functionality in JW Player.

Comment: You mean to zoom into the video?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer yes. zoom and then pan inside the video. either by some kind of built-in UI / API / workarounds

Comment: That is definitely not supported, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Jwplayer does not support this feature, I think you can explore [videoGL](http://plugincc.fabiobiondi.com/?cerchez-project=videogl) library for this

[check here for more information](http://codecanyon.net/item/videogl-3d-html5-video-player-with-filters/7404949)